# Adding class to textarea based on select (jquery to javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have a script that changes the font of a `textarea` when a selection is made in a `select` dropdown. It's written in jQuery.

```
var selectedScheme = '';
$('.addon-select').change(function() {
  $('.addon-custom-textarea').removeClass(selectedScheme).addClass($(this).val());
  selectedScheme = $(this).val();
});
```

> **[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcEa9/86/)**

I would like to re-write this using regular JavaScript. This is what I have so far, but It does not work.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('.addon-select').value == 'arial') {
     document.getElementsByClassName('.addon-custom-textarea').className += ' arial'
}
```

> **[Broken Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcEa9/89/)**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[0]` to target a *single* element.

You can use `classList` to *add* and *remove* classes in an *event listener* - see demo below and [`updated fiddle here`](http://jsfiddle.net/asz2wrvw/):

```js
var selectedScheme;
document.getElementsByClassName('addon-select')[0].addEventListener('change',
  function() {
    if (selectedScheme)
      document.getElementsByClassName('addon-custom-textarea')[0].classList.remove(selectedScheme);
    document.getElementsByClassName('addon-custom-textarea')[0].classList.add(this.value);
    selectedScheme = this.value;

  });
```

```css
input,
select,
textarea {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
/* not important */

.arial {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
.times {
  font-family: 'Times New roman';
}
.courier-new {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
}
.verdana {
  font-family: 'Verdana';
}
```

```html
<select class="addon-select">
  <option selected disabled>Select a font...</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="times">Times New roman</option>
  <option value="courier-new">Courier New</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<br />

<textarea class="addon-custom-textarea" rows="5">This is some text</textarea>
```

Comment: Everybody's comments were very helpful and taught me something about standard JS, but this example worked the best in my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object. So you will have to use an `index` to access a specific element.

Also you have the change event handler missing for vanilla javascript.

So

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.addon-select')
```

is supposed to be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('addon-select')[0]

 OR

document.querySelector('.addon-select')
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.addon-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var textArea = document.querySelector('.addon-custom-textarea');

    textArea.className = 'addon-custom-textarea ' + this.value;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcEa9/93/)**

Answer (score 1):

You missed to attach an `event handler` to the `select`. And also I added `id` to the `select`. If you want to use class, you must access to it like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('addon-select')[0]
```

because `getElementsByClassName` will return you a `array-like object`, and you need ti get the `first item` from it.

```js
document.getElementById('selectFont').addEventListener("change", function(){

    let text = document.querySelector('.addon-custom-textarea');
    text.className = 'addon-custom-textarea ' + this.value;


}, false);
```

```css
input, select, textarea { padding: 10px 10px; width: 200px; }  /* not important */


.arial {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.times {
  font-family: 'Times New roman';
}

.courier-new {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
}

.verdana {
  font-family: 'Verdana';
}
```

```html
<select id="selectFont" class="addon-select">
  <option selected disabled>Select a font...</option>
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="times">Times New roman</option>
  <option value="courier-new">Courier New</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<br />

<textarea class="addon-custom-textarea" rows="5">This is some text</textarea>
```